# How to bind a SharePoint list attachment to a Kendo Grid column dynamically

Tags: c#, json, sharepoint, kendo-ui, grid

I have a SharePoint list where I grab the required rows depending on a dynamically created query, and passing them to the front end using a Json serialized object. I am then using that Json object as the dataSource for Kendo Grid.

Now, some of the rows that I'm pulling are going to have a file attached to them. I want to check if a row has an attachment. And if it has one, I want to place an image (with a link to the attachment) to the corresponding column. The column is static, its going to be there even if there aren't attachments on the list.

How can I check if an item in that Json object has a value in its attachment, and if it does, how do I use that information on the column template?

I can provide additional details if required. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the schema.data configuration can accept a function, so you can parse the information that comes from the server before you bind it to the widget:

[Schema.parse](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.data)

And in the Kendo UI Templates, you can execute fully functional JavaScript, so you can implement a simple if statement:

[Templates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview)

Comment: Didn't know about Scema.parse. Thanks!